# Angular Export to PDF is removing all whitespaces in between. How can I retain the spaces present in "dataAddComment"

Tags: angular

```
public addComSection(doc) {
debugger;
let dataAddComments = this.dataAddComments.nativeElement;
console.log(dataAddComments);
doc.autoTable({
html: dataAddComments, theme: 'striped', tableWidth: 'Wrap',width: 190, styles: {
halign: 'justified'
}, 
 startY: 80,
 didParseCell(data) {
 if (data.row.index === 0) {
    data.cell.styles.fontStyle = 'bold'
    data.cell.styles.textColor = [255, 255, 255];
    data.cell.styles.fillColor = [41, 128, 185];
    /* data.cell.styles.halign = 'left' */
   }
  }
});
```

}

I have the details in dataAddocmments which I want to display in the PDF. But it displays with no whitespaces except "space" no \n.